# How do I manipulate the same function in javascript for two different classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox

I have to use two different sizes of checkbox on the same page. I will determine which size to use based on the checkbox `name`. If `name='room'` I will use the big image of class 'custom-checkbox'. Else if `name='request'`, I will use small image of class `custom-checkbox2`.

Now, how do I modify the below script so that it can determine which class to use based on the name of the checkbox?

CSS:

```
.custom-checkbox{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 3px;
  background: url("../img/big-check-nopass.png") no-repeat;
}
.custom-checkbox:hover{
  background: url("../img/big-check-pass.png") no-repeat;
}
.custom-checkbox.selected{
  background: url("../img/big-check-pass.png") no-repeat;
}
.custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]{
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;            
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0;
  /* CSS hacks for older browsers */
  _noFocusLine: expression(this.hideFocus=true); 
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
}
/* Let's Beautify Our Form */

label{
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 0;
}

/*for small cehckbox*/
.custom-checkbox2{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 3px;
  background: url("../img/small-check-nopass.png") no-repeat;
}
.custom-checkbox2:hover{
  background: url("../img/small-check-pass.png") no-repeat;
}
.custom-checkbox2.selected{
  background: url("../img/small-check-pass.png") no-repeat;
}
.custom-checkbox2 input[type="checkbox"]{
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;            
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0;
  /* CSS hacks for older browsers */
  _noFocusLine: expression(this.hideFocus=true); 
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
}
/* Let's Beautify Our Form */

label2{
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 0;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function customCheckbox(checkboxName){
  var checkBox = $('input[name="'+ checkboxName +'"]');
  $(checkBox).each(function(){
    $(this).wrap( "<span class='custom-checkbox'></span>" );
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
    }
  });
  $(checkBox).click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("selected");
  });
}
$(document).ready(function (){
  customCheckbox("room[]");
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large-3 right columns">
       <label><input type="checkbox" name="room[]" value="" /></label>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="large-3 right columns">
       <label><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" value="" /></label>
 </div>
</div>
```

EDIT**

Removed function and modified script:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function (){
        $("input:checkbox").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("name") == "room[]") {
       $(this).wrap( "<span class='custom-checkbox'></span>" );
       if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
            }
    } else if($(this).attr("name") == "request[]") {
       $(this).wrap( "<span class='custom-checkbox2'></span>" );
       if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
            }
    }
});

    })
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add your html code please?, if you can use fiddle

Comment: you actually probably don't need any js for this, use the attrib css selector: `[name='room']`instead of `.custom-checkbox`

Comment: @xzengga I added the HTML part..Can you help?

Comment: so you want to update all the checkboxes on the page when the page loads so the right image displays? In that case you probably don't need to pass an argument, get a list of all checkboxes, check their name, and give them the proper class

Comment: @dandavis, I'm using js because I want different images for selected and non-selected state.

Comment: @samantha: ok, but you can also apply those in CSS using the `:checked` psudo selector. i just think using js for presentation that CSS can handle is the wrong way to go about it; everything i see above can be done in pure CSS

Comment: can you give them different class names?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad, yes I want the checkbox with name=room to have bigger image and the one with name=request to have smaller images as specified in the class.

Comment: @dandavis, can you give me the css then, coz I'm unsure how to write it using the pseudo

Comment: `:checked` replaces  `.custom-checkbox.selected` , but if you're needing to style `.custom-checkbox`, then you need that element, or change that selector to `label`, possibly being more-specific if needed. with that, you would no longer need the js, if i'm understanding the code.

Comment: @dandavis , I tried but it doesn't display the background images for each state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "each" jQuery function, which will check every inputs of the checkbox type on the page. So, you simple get it's name, if it's "room[]", add the `custom-checkbox-big-size` class to the span wrap, if it's name is "request[]", add the `custom-checkbox-small-size` class to the span wrap (I changed your CSS to make the things simple).

**JS:**

```
var wrapSpan = $('<span class="custom-checkbox-span"</span>');
$('input:checkbox').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        wrapSpanspan.addClass('checked');
    }
    if($(this).attr("name") == "room[]") {
        wrapSpan.addClass("custom-checkbox-big-size");
    }
    if($(this).attr("name") == "request[]") {
        wrapSpan.addClass("custom-checkbox-small-size");
    }
    $(this).wrap(wrapSpan).hide();
});

$(".custom-checkbox-span").on("mouseup",function(){
    checkSpan($(this));
});

function checkSpan(el) {
    if(el.hasClass("selected")) {
        el.removeClass("selected");
        el.children().prop("checked",false);
    } else {
        el.addClass("selected");
        el.children().prop("checked",true);
    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.custom-checkbox-big-size {
    background:red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.custom-checkbox-big-size:hover, .custom-checkbox-big-size.selected {
    background:yellow;
}
.custom-checkbox-small-size {
    background:blue;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.custom-checkbox-small-size:hover, .custom-checkbox-small-size.selected {
    background:green;
}
```

Check the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ediejohnny/98qafxa5/6/). I did it with colors, because I don't have your original images, you have to change the `background: color;` rules.

Comment: as I checked your fiddle, that's exactly what I want, but I'm unsure how to use integrate it with my function. As you mentioned I tried placing it after the last bracket, yet it doesn't make any changes. Could you help please.

Comment: I have added more code to the jsFiddle. If your function just toggle that selected class from the checkboxes, that'll do the job as you expected. But let me know if you need that spans and I'll update again.

Comment: now I placed  your previous fiddle version script. It shows big or small checkbox depends on the name of the checkbox as i wanted. But the function is not working. The function suppose to show different background image upon the state of the checkbox.

Comment: But you want the background in which element? Inside the checkbox or outside? Or a specific element, or the whole body background?

Comment: the function will replace the checkbox with image for normal, hover and selected state as per the css.

Comment: I replaced this line in your script  $(this).addClass("custom-checkbox"); with  $(this).wrap( "<span class='custom-checkbox'></span>" );............ then the images shown but unable to hold the select.

Comment: please have a look at the edited section as I updated my script from yours..But it persist with one prblm which is unable to hold the select.

Comment: Hmm, I still can't see the point, check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ediejohnny/98qafxa5/4/). I replaced the images with red and blue because I don't have your images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75346/discussion-between-edie-johnny-and-samantha).

Answer (score 0):

This is handled in the selector, assuming you are using CSS3,like so...

```
input[type*='checkbox'][name*='room'] {
    ... styles here
}
```

Comment: Added the * for substring matching do to the fact that the name attribute is an array

Comment: I appreciate that, but I prefer to use js as it works fine. Only need to modify it so that it can dictate which class to use based on the checkbox name.Could you help with that please?

Comment: Then you should be able to replace the first line inside the function with the a selector similar to the one above adding the * character right before the equal sign. ex: var checkBox = $('input[name*="'+ checkboxName +'"]');